# Using $realtime to evaluate wait() in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Is it possible to use $realtime to evaluate a condition for `wait()` in systemverilog? For example, the code below doesn't work for me:

```
wait(($realtime - start_time >= some_specific_value) || (cancel_wait))
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because `wait(expression)` needs to see an operand in the expression change its value before reevaluating the expression. `$realtime` is just a function call with no operand arguments.

One possible alternative that gives you the behavior you want

```
fork
  #some_specific_value;
  wait (cancel_wait);
join_any
```

Comment: So I fork a task in a reactive sequence that needs to wait a certain number of cycles before it can start an item on a sequencer. Within these cycles, we could just abandon sending the item, or change the item before we send it. Is the sequence not the right place wait? Should it be in the sequencer maybe?

Comment: That is a different, more involved question, but yes you could use a sequence to delay the start. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/timer/counter-implementation-uvm#reply-45996